# adding an object to an existing javascript/JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following objects printed out on my console logs:

[image]

I assume that this is an array of two objects (1 and 2 respectively). However I wanted to create an object of similar format to object 1 and 2 and then push it to this array, how do I do so? I tried doing a push on this, however it gives me:

```
 Object #<Object> has no method 'push'
```

Comment: share the code please...

Comment: That's **not** an array, it's an object that happens to have keys of "1" and "2".

Comment: Plz don't ever post code image.

Comment: @Parse which code you want?

Comment: Have a look at [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). But if you have numerically consecutive keys anyways, why not use a proper array instead of an object?

Comment: @adit The code that produces the error? Also, the code that produces/retrieves the object you think is an array.

Comment: photoshop console doesn't return any error for me, your code picture looks safe thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, this an **object**, not an array (the constructor function is `Object` and the `__proto__` object as well).

If you have numerically consecutive keys, it would be best to keep the objects in an array and then you would be able to `.push` a new value onto it.

However, if that's not possible, but you still want to add a new object with an increased key, you have to find the current maximum key first. For example:

```
function get_max_key(obj) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, Object.keys(obj));
}

obj[get_max_key(obj) + 1] = new_value;
```

Alternatively you could just *count* the number of values in the object (depending on the actual situation and the value of the keys):

```
function get_number_of_properties(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length;
}
```

To avoid extracting the keys and process them every time, you could keep the current length or highest key in an extra variable or as a property on the object. For example, you could assign a `length` property to the object and thus make it an *array-like* object:

```
var obj = {
    length: 0
};
```

The advantage is that you can apply many (if not all) array methods to that object. You could even use `Array.prototype.push` to add a new property:

```
[].push.call(obj, new_value);
```

and it would update the `length` property for you.

But again, in this case you could just directly use an array instead.

---

Have a look at [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to learn more about objects.

Answer (score 0):

[Anthony Grist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/552438/anthony-grist) is totaly right: this is not an array.

You can think of this more as a hasharray, where you access values using a key.

All you have to do to add data to your object is for example:

```
yourObject.subObjectName = {content:"Your content",created:"2013"};
```

In javascript you can simply add any value to an object using the dot notation.